# why we can't implement methods from interface to abstract class, without modifying "public"?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, access-modifiers

interface:

```
interface MasterPlan{
    void getRate();
}
```

abstract class:

```
abstract class Plan implements MasterPlan{
    abstract void getRate();
} }
```

At this case, I can't implement `MasterPlan` interface without using `public` modifier in `getRate()` method.

```
public abstract void getRate();
```

this is working with normal behavior.

I know default modifier is `default` in interfaces. what is the reason for this error without `public` modifier in implemented abstract class?

Comment: "I know default modifier is "default" in interfaces. " ... then your knowledge is flawed. The default modifier is "public" in interfaces. This issue is even proof of this.

Comment: Methods defined in an interface have to be public by contract.

Comment: In a **class** the lack of a 'public` (or `private`) access modifier is, in itself, a declaration of access: it declares the method to have package-private access.  That behavior doesn't change even if the method declaration happens to be implementing a method of an interface.  So you have to write `public` just as you would for any other public method. And because you're implementing an interface method , it _does_ have to be public.

Comment: Tom and deHaar, yeah got the point.. It is "public". not a "default". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing the thing that every method in a `Interface` is `public`. So if you got an `abstract` class which implements the `Interface` the methods that are in there are `public`. You can't change the visibility of a defined method.

Comment: yeah got the point.. It is "public". not a "default". Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly public.

interface have methods having implicit properties and once the method is declared after that when you define it or implement it you can't change the access modifier of it.

or else you can declare your class as private,protected etc.

[oracle document defining interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html)

you can ask more eager to help.